# How to access referenced table from ASPX in-line code (datagridview control)

Tags: asp.net, sql, datagridview, inline-code

i am trying to bind data to a datagridview control on an ASPX webpage and am using something like this..

```
<asp:TemplateField HeaderText="MyField">
    <ItemTemplate>
        <%# DataBinder.Eval(Container.DataItem, "MyField") %>
    </ItemTemplate>
</asp:TemplateField>
```

the problem i am having is that the data for the 'MyField' field is actually an integer that is a reference to a string value in another sql table.

Does anyone know how i can reformat my code line above to show the string value instead of the int value?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to change your SQL query to return the string using a `JOIN`.

Comment: I'm not sure i follow. What SQL query? Are you suggesting i cannot achieve the desired results by modifying the inline-code?

Comment: What does the data come from?

Comment: If you're original query isn't returning the string value there is no way to show it on the page :-) You need to return the string field on you're sql query in order to show it. That's what SLaks wanted to say.